# How to find runID from artifact in azure devops yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml pipeline that produces an artifact, and in another pipeline I want to consume this artifact and use it. The specific problem is that I can no longer find the runID from the run that produced the artifact.

**Previously**

In the second pipeline I used to be able to get the runID from previous pipeline by running:

```
$(resources.pipeline.<artifactName>.runID)
```

I was using the shortcut to download the artifact to the entire pipeline like:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: <artifactName>
    source: <pipelineName>
```

**Currently** *(not working)*

Now I am using a task that will instead download the artifact to a specific stage (not to the entire pipeline), and I select it through different tags on the pipeline-run. I follow this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops

Specifically:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          inputs:
            source: 'specific'
            project: '<myProjectName>'
            pipeline: <firstPipelineID>
            artifact: '<artifactName>'
            targetPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
            tags: <myTag>
```

I try to get the runID from the artifact almost like previously:

```
$(Pipeline.Workspace.<artifactName>.runID)
```

I can not get the runID. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you need to get the runID when using the DownloadPipelineArtifact task.

I am afraid that there is no such variable can directly get the runID.

When you use the DownloadPipelineArtifact task to download the artifacts, it will generate a variable: `$(DOWNLOADPIPELINEARTIFACT.BUILDNUMBER)`.

It has the same value as the variable `$(resources.pipeline.<artifactName>.runID)`

You can change to use the variable: `$(DOWNLOADPIPELINEARTIFACT.BUILDNUMBER)` to get the RunId.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.

I can also add that the variable is overwritten if you download another artifact in the same pipeline. At least when I try it in two different stages.